# How do I do push notifications in Corona SDK for Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, coronasdk

Is there a way to do push notifications using Corona SDK for Android? How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

According to their [RoadMap](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/roadmap/), Push notification on Android is **not** possible yet. Sorry.

You might also want to follow Local notifications (which is also not available to Android platforms in Corona) - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149864/local-notifications-for-corona-sdk-android) for more details.

On a personal note, We're also really waiting for both.

Answer (score 0):

Now Its in the Corona new build. Just see the sample code of corona sdk. In notification folder there are local as well as google push notification.