# Local Notifications for Corona SDK (Android)

Tags: android, uilocalnotification, coronasdk

Is there a way to implement local notifications while using the Corona SDK? This is android specific, as we have already found the iOS directions.

Cheers!

Comment: you can implement local notification using some android logic of alarm manager, notification and broadcast/service.

Answer (score 1):

Local notification for now is iOS only on Corona... The Android version is not done yet.

When it gets done I will see to edit this with the directions of the android version.

Answer (score 1):

Local notifications are done for iOS and Android: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/scheduleNotification.html

It doesn't appear there is a way to set the icon for these notifications, but I'm sure they will add it at some point.

As of now (2012.12.07),  push (remote) notifications are available on iOS, but NOT Android.